# How to access form parameters using RestEasy REST.Request?

Tags: java, javascript, rest, resteasy

I have my form below:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1">
    <fieldset>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label>Project:</label>
                <select id="project" name="project" required></select>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="button" onclick="request();">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I created a request() function on the onclick event of the input button. I changed the input type to button because I didn't want the page to reload.

The request function uses the RestEasy REST.Request class to create a custom rest request. I used setEntity on the REST.Request object but I don't know how to access that information on the server side.

Below is the request function:

```
request: function() {
    var myRequest = new REST.Request();
    var form1 = document.forms["form1"];

    var projectTxt = form1.elements["project"].value;

    myRequest.setURI(REST.apiURL + "/request/item");
    myRequest.setMethod("GET");
    myRequest.setEntity({project:projectTxt});

    myRequest.execute(function(status, request, entity) {
        if (status === 200 && request.readyState === 4) {
            // entity is always null
            sessionStorage.setItem("project", entity);
            console.log("entity=" + entity);
        }
    });
},
```

In the above code, entity in the function passed to myRequest.execute() is always null.

Here is the Java code:

```
@Path("item")
@GET
public String itemFormatRequest(@FormParam("project") String project)
{
    // project is always null
    return "blarg!!! project is " + project;
}
```

In the above code, project is null. I've tried using *@QueryParam* and that doesn't work either. Am I just using this incorrectly or is there something else I'm missing? I've done much trial and error by changing @GET to @POST in both the javascript and java codes. Have also tried adding *@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")* in the java code and that didn't work.

The only thing I did get to work is adding query parameters to the REST.request object like this:

```
myRequest.addQueryParameter("project", projectTxt);
```

And then I'm able to retrieve this using *(@QueryParam("project") String project)*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `GET` as request method. A `GET` is intended to retrieve data and so you don't pass an entity. If you just want to read data of a selected project you can use a `GET` in conjunction with a `@QueryParam`. But then you don't pass an entity. Just add the queryParameter:

```
myRequest.addQueryParameter('project', projectTxt);
```

If you want to pass data to the server you should change the method of the request to `POST` (in the client and the server code). Also your entity is JSON but your server code expects a `@FormParam`. The `REST.Request` object has a `addForm` and add `addFormParameter` method. So one of the following should also work (untested):

```
myRequest.addForm('form1', form1);
```

or

```
myRequest.addFormParameter('project', projectTxt);
```